Using gcov on a freestanding environment with riscv64-unknow-elf-gcc 13.2.0
All
I am trying to use gcov on a freestanding environment with riscv64-unknow-elf-gcc 13.2.0.
I tried to follow the idea of gcc gcov tutorial here. And it works on my host system.
Then I try to porting this example to my riscv64 environment, which is a baremetal MCU, and has no file system and stdlib.
#Compile
riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -mcmodel=medany -static \
  -O0 -ffast-math -fno-common -fno-builtin-printf \
  --coverage -fprofile-info-section -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections \
  -g -c test_gcov.c

#Link
riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -static -nostdlib -nostartfiles \
  --coverage -T ../common/test_gcov.ld *.o -Wl,-Map=test_gcov.riscv.map \
  -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--verbose -o test_gcov.riscv


It fails while linking
attempt to open /opt/riscv/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/13.2.0/libgcov.a succeeded
/opt/riscv/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/13.2.0/libgcov.a
(/opt/riscv/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/13.2.0/libgcov.a)_gcov_merge_add.o
(/opt/riscv/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/13.2.0/libgcov.a)_gcov.o
/opt/riscv/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/13.2.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/ld: warning: test_gcov.riscv has a LOAD segment with RWX permissions
/opt/riscv/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/13.2.0/../../../../riscv64-unknown-elf/bin/ld: /opt/riscv/lib/gcc/riscv64-unknown-elf/13.2.0/libgcov.a(_gcov.o): in function `gcov_read_bytes':
/media/jmst/tmpSSD/riscv-gnu-toolchain/build-gcc-newlib-stage2/riscv64-unknown-elf/libgcc/../../.././gcc/libgcc/libgcov-driver.c:399:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `fread'

It seems the libgcov.a need a define of fread, which is stdlib function here.
Is there anyway to let the coverage code not use stdlib, since file system is not avaliable on my system.
Thanks

How about just providing a dummy fread function if you don't need to actually read anything ?

try using the linker flags
-lnosys ... this indicates that no operating system is present. provides empty stubs for system function
And also
-specs=nano.spec ... this indicates that the newlib function should be used which is a scaled implementation of some stand library function to run on embedded system
